# Generic UIView Initializer with closure in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, closures

I want to write a generic UIView initializer so I can initialize UIViews by passing the configuration closure in initializer.What I want is the below syntax to work for all UIView subclasses.

```
let button = UIButton() {
    $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    $0.frame = CGRect(x: 220, y: 30, width: 100, height: 100)
    $0.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
}
```

I have written the convenience initializer in UIView extension **but with this I am not able to set UIView subclasses properties like the setTitle(_:for) property for UIButton** because in closure it is always sending UIView type parameter instead of the specific subclass type.

Here is my initializer.

```
extension UIView {

    convenience init<T: UIView>(_ configurations: (T) -> Void) {
        self.init()

        configurations(self as! T)
    }
}
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**NOTE:** I was able to achieve the above behaviour of initializing UIView and subtypes with closure using protocol but I wonder if this can be achieved this way i.e. Writing convenience initializer in UIView extension without any additional protocol.

Comment: initializer always meant to return instance of class where it instantiated. Look closely, in your convenience initializer you don’t decide what is the return type, even you don’t return anything.

Comment: But in swift the initializer didn't work that way ? Because when we write convenience initializers we didn't specify any return type just name it "init" and it automatically returns the instance.

Comment: yes, i am saying the same thing. You cannot decide what type it should return. It always return the same type where it declared.

Comment: @NajeeburRehman Why do you want to initialise this way?

Comment: But there may be some way to achieve this using generics, isn’t it ?

Comment: Because this syntax seems good to me.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the problem is generic `T` does not resolved as `UIButton`. You didn't specify what is the parameter type of `configuration` closure is.

```
let button = UIButton() { (b: UIButton) in
    b.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    b.frame = CGRect(x: 220, y: 30, width: 100, height: 100)
    b.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
}
```

Now the `T` generic will be seen `UIButton`.

Comment: Will this work with the initializer in the question ?

Comment: Yes, but the painful part is specifying the type everytime, otherwise passed `$0` will be treated as `UIView` instance.

Comment: Yes that’s the problem even after specifying that we are initializing UIButton with round brackets () but still we need to specify the type in the closure.

Comment: @RatulSharker But why isn't `T` inferred as `UIButton`? Doesn't the compiler know this?

Comment: The type `T` is based on the parameter passed, not on the type on which the function is called. @badhanganesh

Comment: But why the above approach doesn't work even I am typecasting the self to T when passing to the configuration closure.

Comment: Can you explain where does `T` get to know, that `T` is now type of `UIButton` ? @NajeeburRehman

Comment: try `print("~> \(T.self)")` without specifying the parameter inside the constructor. What does it says without parameter and with parameter ?

Comment: Nowhere, I understand your point. This is the possible solution but I need something that can be done at initializer side so to avoid the boilerplate code for every object initialization and to use short hand notation($0) in closure. BTW thanks.

Comment: printing T.self giving the exact type but when I cast the self to T then why it is not casted to the exact type ?

Comment: When you added constraint `<T: UIView>` it assume that it would be of type UIView, unless specifying compiler will throw error `error: generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`.

Comment: Do not downvote an answer, without explanation.Put an explanation (if you have any) before downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask about is not trivial using UIKit. In SwiftUI styling of views is declarative, but using a Builder pattern, where each view modifier returns the view so that you can chain customization. However, you specifically asked about being able to customize views by passing **closure**s, see *Solution 2* below. But first I wanted to present a different approach, using ArrayLiterals with enums, see Solution 1.

## Solution 1 - ViewComposer

[ViewComposer](https://github.com/Sajjon/ViewComposer) is a library (that I developed some years ago) for declaring views using array literals of enums, which allows you to declare views like so:

```swift
let button: UIButton = [.color(.red), .text("Red"), .textColor(.blue)]
let label: UILabel = [.text("Hello World"), .textColor(.red)]
lazy var emailField: UITextField = [.font(.big), .height(50), .placeholder("Email"), .delegate(self)]
```

Scroll down to [the bottom of the README and you will see a list of supported views](https://github.com/Sajjon/ViewComposer#supported-uikit-views), most view classes are supported.

How ViewComposer works is a bit too complicated to post here, but have a look at the code!

## Solution 2 - Zhip

In my [open source iOS Zilliqa wallet app called Zhip](https://github.com/OpenZesame/Zhip) I've created yet another solution for easily configuring UIViews, much similar to your question.

Here here is [ReceiveView](https://github.com/OpenZesame/Zhip/blob/develop/Source/Scenes/1_Main/2_Main/B_Receive/Receive/ReceiveView.swift), which looks like this

[image: zhip_receive]

Having this code:

```swift
final class ReceiveView: ScrollableStackViewOwner {

    private lazy var qrImageView            = UIImageView()
    private lazy var addressTitleLabel      = UILabel()
    private lazy var addressValueTextView   = UITextView()
    private lazy var copyMyAddressButton    = UIButton()
    private lazy var addressAndCopyButton   = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [addressValueTextView, copyMyAddressButton])
    private lazy var addressViews           = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [addressTitleLabel, addressAndCopyButton])
    private lazy var requestingAmountField  = FloatingLabelTextField()
    private lazy var requestPaymentButton   = UIButton()

    // MARK: - StackViewStyling
    lazy var stackViewStyle = UIStackView.Style([
        qrImageView,
        addressViews,
        requestingAmountField,
        .spacer,
        requestPaymentButton
        ])

    override func setup() {
        setupSubviews()
    }
}
```

and config of views:

```swift
private typealias € = L10n.Scene.Receive
private extension ReceiveView {

    // swiftlint:disable:next function_body_length
    func setupSubviews() {
        qrImageView.withStyle(.default)

        addressTitleLabel.withStyle(.title) {
            $0.text(€.Label.myPublicAddress)
        }

        addressValueTextView.withStyle(.init(
            font: UIFont.Label.body,
            isEditable: false,
            isScrollEnabled: false,
            // UILabel and UITextView horizontal alignment differs, change inset: stackoverflow.com/a/45113744/1311272
            contentInset: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -5, bottom: 0, right: -5)
            )
        )

        copyMyAddressButton.withStyle(.title(€.Button.copyMyAddress))
        copyMyAddressButton.setHugging(.required, for: .horizontal)

        addressAndCopyButton.withStyle(.horizontal)
        addressViews.withStyle(.default) {
            $0.layoutMargins(.zero)
        }

        requestingAmountField.withStyle(.decimal)

        requestPaymentButton.withStyle(.primary) {
            $0.title(€.Button.requestPayment)
        }
    }
}
```

Let's go through config of some of the views:

We config a `UILabel` called `addressTitleLabel` with this code:

```swift
addressTitleLabel.withStyle(.title) {
    $0.text(€.Label.myPublicAddress)
}
```

1. `€` is just a local typealias to a localization context for translated strings with the key `L10n.Scene.Receive.Label.myPublicAddress`, so for an iOS device with English language setting that will translate to the string `"My public address"`.
2. `.withStyle(.title)` is a call to a function called `withStyle` that I have declared on `UILabel`, see [code on Github here](https://github.com/OpenZesame/Zhip/blob/develop/Source/Extensions/UIKit/Views%2BStyleable/Styling/UILabel%2BStyling.swift#L72-L78), being:

```
@discardableResult
func withStyle(
    _ style: UILabel.Style,
    customize: ((UILabel.Style) -> UILabel.Style)? = nil
) -> UILabel {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let style = customize?(style) ?? style
    apply(style: style)
    return self
}
```

3. We pass `.title` as an argument to the function, and in the function declaration above you can see that the type is `UILabel.Style`, meaning we have declared a static variable called `title` as an extension on `UILabel.Style`, being some default style. This is somewhat similar to [SwiftUI's Font, which has an enum case called `title`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/textstyle/title) (but I created this long before the release of `SwiftUI` ). Where in the SwiftUI case it is a preset of the `Font`, where as in my case it is a preset of a whole `UILabel.Style`. Let's have a look at it!
4. `UILabel.Style`, [here is `title`](https://github.com/OpenZesame/Zhip/blob/develop/Source/Extensions/UIKit/Views+Styleable/Styling/UILabel+Styling.swift#L144-L148):

```swift
static var title: UILabel.Style {
    return UILabel.Style(
        font: UIFont.title
    )
}
```

So it is just calling the initializer with the value `UIFont.title` as font.

5. Customize block - in the `withStyle` function, the second argument is a trailing closure, being a closure to customise the preset style. In the case of `addressTitleLabel`, here is where we set the `text` property of the `UILabel`.
6. Multi customizing in closure - in another view - [`UnlockAppWithPincodeView`](https://github.com/OpenZesame/Zhip/blob/develop/Source/Scenes/1_Main/1_UnlockAppWithPincode/UnlockAppWithPincodeView.swift#L66-L68) we perform multiple customizations of a `UILabel`:

```swift
func setupSubviews() {
    descriptionLabel.withStyle(.body) {
        $0
            .text(€.label)
            .textAlignment(.center)
    }
}
```

7. How styles are applied: Earlier above we saw the code for `withStyle`, which calls [`apply(style: style)`](https://github.com/OpenZesame/Zhip/blob/develop/Source/Extensions/UIKit/Views+Styleable/Styling/UILabel+Styling.swift#L59-L70) before returning the view (UILabel). This is where our view gets styled. Which just does exactly what you would expect, it applies every config:

```swift
extension UILabel {
    func apply(style: Style) {
        text = style.text
        font = style.font ?? UIFont.Label.body
        textColor = style.textColor ?? .defaultText
        numberOfLines = style.numberOfLines ?? 1
        textAlignment = style.textAlignment ?? .left
        backgroundColor = style.backgroundColor ?? .clear
        if let minimumScaleFactor = style.adjustsFontSizeMinimumScaleFactor {
            adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            self.minimumScaleFactor = minimumScaleFactor
        }
    }
}
```

8. I've then applied this pattern for every UIKit view I would like to support. Which is some boilerplate copy paste for sure (In above-mentioned `ViewComposer` lib I made some more effort of creating bridging protocols etc, but that also resulted in a much more complicated code base). Please have a look at the directory in Zhip where all this code is placed - [`../Source/Extensions/UIKit`](https://github.com/OpenZesame/Zhip/tree/develop/Source/Extensions/UIKit).
9. Especially thanks to static presets on each style this results in a pretty neat and short syntax for creating and styling of UIViews.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You have done a lot of work to implement these approaches but I was just wondering if this approach could be made possible with writing some sort of generic initializer for UIView and it seems it is not possible that way.

Comment: Yes, in ViewComposer I do that, but it requires protocols which groups together views having similar properties. The array literal with enums for properties results in a view type specified by Generics.

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT:

I did it with this

```swift
public protocol WithCreation: AnyObject {}

extension NSObject: WithCreation {}

public extension WithCreation where Self: NSObject {
    init(_ closure: (Self) -> Void) {
        self.init()
        closure(self)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
UIImageView { $0.image = UIImage(named: "whatever") }
UILabel { $0.text = "We did it! :) " }
UIButton { $0.setTitle("OK", for: .normal) }
```

## OLD ANSWER

The closer I've got to what you're trying to do is this:

```
public extension UIView {
    convenience init(_ closure: (Self) -> Void) {
        self.init()
        closure(self)
    }
}
```

Which is used simply with

```
UIView { $0.backgroundColor = .red }
```

Main issue is that is not working with UIView subclasses like

```
UIImageView { $0.image = UIImage(named: "whatever") }
```

It doesn't compile and the error is `value of type Self has no member 'image'`

This is just by using initializers, and I think we're hitting a limitation of Swift Compiler.

However, you can try this workaround:

```swift
public protocol WithPropertyAssignment {}

public extension WithPropertyAssignment where Self: AnyObject {

func with(_ closure: @escaping (Self) -> Void) -> Self {
        closure(self)
        return self
    }
}

extension NSObject: WithPropertyAssignment {}
```

and then you can do

```swift
UILabel().with { $0.text = "Ciao" }
UIImage().with { $0.image = UIImage() }
```

Which is not quite the same, but it's still readable I guess...

Answer (score 0):

How about something as simple as this?

```
@discardableResult
func config<T>(_ object: T,
               _ block (inout T) throws -> Void) rethrows -> T {
    var object = object
    try block(&object)
    return object
}
```

Use it like this:

```
let view = config(UIView()) {
    $0.backgroundColor = .white
    $0.frame.size = .init(width: 50, height: 50)
    // ... other configuration code ...
}
```

It looks like a lazy initializer, but it isn't. It's a direct definition (you can use `let`). If you need to refer to any other property in your code, then you might need to change it to a `lazy var` assignment, but there's a bit of a side effect that `lazy var` is a mutating declaration.

The `inout` for the block parameter allows this to work not only with reference types, but with value types as well.

I use this all the time in my code, and I'm surprised that nobody has responded to this question with such a solution.